# How to see jvm metrics report in ganglia web

Tags: jvm, jmx, ganglia

I need to see jvm metrics on ganglia report, I've set up jmxetric on a node and see jvm metrics when using simple 'telnet localhost 8649'.

I have ganglia-web with gmond/gmetad running on another machine and it shows standard reports such as cpu/memory, but not new jvm metrics.

Should I configure ganglia-web manually to make it show jvm group as well?

I'm using ganglia 3.3.7.

Comment: Do you mean the metrics don't show up in the node specific view for your jmxetric node? Or do you want to view them as a combined report on the front page? Are the .rrd files corresponding to jmx metrics present under /var/lib/ganglia/rrds on the gmetad node ?

Comment: Yes, I open summary view, then go into the node where jmxetric is installed and I only see 'standard' metrics.
/var/lib/ganglia/rrds on gmetad node also contains 'standard' ones like cpu*.rrd, disk*.rrd, mem*.rrd.

Comment: Igor, We are looking at the same, and I also found a package called jmxtrans (https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/blob/master/README.md) Did you consider this package at all? It seems like it will also do the same, but may be a little more flexible. I was trying to decide which to you and was looking for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to configure ganglia-web to show new metrics, they just show up given their metadata is also known to the listening gmond and gmetad has thus received and written them to rrd databases.

Are you using unicast mode? You may be sending the jmxetric metrics only to the gmond running on the jmxetric host. Gmond won't forward the metrics to the ganglia-web/gmetad/gmond host unless you add them to a collection group in `gmond.conf` at the jmxetric host.

Also in unicast mode, make sure `gmond.conf` has `send_metadata_interval` set to something other than 0 (default). This prevents metrics from disappearing if you restart gmond on the gmetad node.

Another way is to send the jmx metrics directly from jmxetric to the gmond running on the gmetad node.

Comment: I'm using unicast mode. My main problem was actually mismatch between host name reported by gmond and jmxetrc jvm agent. They ended up in a separate 'localhost' directory on my gmetad ganglia host. 

For some reason I don't need to change send_metadata_interval, metrics get properly forwarded from my jmxetric host to gmetad/ganglia-web host.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question, here are the steps I needed to do to see jvm reports in ganglia web:

- git clone and build https://github.com/ganglia/jmxetric (mvn package)
- create superjar from gmetric4j-1.0.2.jar/jmxetric-1.0.2.jar/oncrpc-1.0.7.jar (to avoid class loading issues, what is recommended approach?)
- add agent when launching jvm:
- -javaagent:/etc/zoomdata/jmxetric-1.0.2.jar=host=MYHOST_AS_IN_GMOND_CONF,port=8649,mode=unicast,wireformat31x=true,process=PROCESS_NAME,config=/etc/jmxetric.xml"
- jmxmetric.xml as in https://github.com/ganglia/jmxetric

Notes:
Host name used in javaagent must match the one used in gmond.conf
host name/port/mode/process can be specified as -javaagent option and also in jmxetric.xml, If you need to deploy to several machines, better to remove jvm and ganglia nodes from xml and define everything via -javaagent parameters. xml will only contain list of jvm metrics and can be copied to all machines.